# Unable to locate DeviceSupport Directory iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, delphi-xe, firemonkey

I know there is already a topic about this, but it is 1 year old.

Whenever I try to debug my FireMonkey application on my iPad ( iOS 7.1 ) I get this error:

> Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory matched with connected device
>   info. Please run Xcode Organizer.

I develop my apps in Windows and have a MacBook Pro running Maverick. The iPad is connected and there is a green light next to the iPad in Xcode.

I have the iOS 7.1 SDK selected in **RAD Studio XE5**.

It deploys successfully on the iPad, but I cannot debug.

I recently upgraded my iPad to 7.1, because there was an version error all of a sudden. Then  I also upgraded my Mac OS and Xcode.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck in the same problem, then, I found [this guide](https://pjstrnad.com/upgrading-ipadiphone-7-1-unable-locate-devicesupport-directory-matched-connected-device-info/).

I just followed steps d), e) and f). That worked for me.

> d) go to folder /Users//Library/Developer/XCode/iOS DeviceSupport
>
> e) There should be folder of your version and version identification –
>   in my case it’s 7.1 (11d167). In my case there was folder 7.1
>   (11d169), but not 11d167. That’s because my iPhone 11d167, but the
>   iPad Air 11d169. I think it’s a bug in Xcode Organizer that that the
>   correct folder wasn’t created.
>
> f) Just take any existing folder and copy it under correct name.

P.S.: The path in step d) is hidden, you need to copy in Terminal or make hidden files visible.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, as the links may become broken. Could you summarize the key parts here?

Comment: d) go to folder /Users/<your name>/Library/Developer/XCode/iOS DeviceSupport

e) There should be folder of your version and version identification – in my case it’s 7.1 (11d167). In my case there was folder 7.1 (11d169), but not 11d167. That’s because my iPhone 11d167, but the iPad Air 11d169. I think it’s a bug in Xcode Organizer that that the correct folder wasn’t created.

Comment: Thanks! In the future, you'll want to include such information in your answer itself. I've edited your answer to include this information.

Comment: Or hold down the Option key to navigate to "Library" from within Finder.